# Modernizr.load on v3 does not exist?

Tags: javascript, modernizr

I want to use `Modernizr.load` function with v3, as v3 adds some tests not present with previous 2.8.x versions.  I used this `load` function without any issue on those previous versions.

I go the page http://v3.modernizr.com/, check the tests I want to use, but I cannot find the APIs nor in the list of selectable APIs, nor in the code when I download the development version.
But still, it is present on their documentation on http://v3.modernizr.com/docs/

Have i done something wrong?  Should I download another js file?

Comment: is it there in the production version?

Comment: It's a bit messy, I checked few tests and click on generate, I get a custom minified version, and get the error <code>Modernizr.load is not a function</code>.  So I would say no, it is not in the production version and I cannot select in the window to include this API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Modernizr.load was removed from v3.0](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/issues/1182)

Comment: Thanks, it seems removed from the file, but not from the documentation : [doc](http://v3.modernizr.com/docs/).  Anyway, I guess I have to find another way, and yepnope.js seems deprecated as well on their site.  Too bad, it was quite easy to write and it seems the alternative is not so simple.

Comment: the v3 site isn't really a new site. its just a new builder for v3. new.modernizr.com would be a better place to check for docs

Comment: Thanks, I will use this link.